# JQuery Cross Domain JSON always results in XHR 200 error

Tags: json, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to use JQuery JSON cross domain query to display some data on my pages.
I am getting XHR 200 error all the time, If I query data using a browser request (direct URL), I am able to collect the data as a valid JSON.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'www.mytestdomain.com/?some=paramters',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
           //some display logic is here, 
           //which is working fine 
           //if in same domain using json and not as jsonp

            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, thrownError) {
            throwServiceError(xhr, status, thrownError);
        }
    });
```

---

```
  //function to show specific jq error
function throwServiceError(xhr, status, thrownError) {
$("#error-wrapper").empty();
switch (xhr.status) {
    case 404:
        $("#error-wrapper").append('File not found');
        break;
    case 500:
        $("#error-wrapper").append('Server error');
        break;
    case 200:
        $("#error-wrapper").append(xhr.status + ":- " + thrownError);
        break;
    case 0:
        $("#error-wrapper").append('Request aborted');
        break;
    default:
        $("#error-wrapper").append('Unknown error ' + xhr.status);
        break;
}
}
```

Note: I tried using the callback functions and callback=? in the request URL, however the result remained same, please suggest the solution which can work.

Comment: What is your server returning from the jsonp request?

Comment: does the server support jsonp

Comment: It says Request Aborted - 200, and how we can come to know that jsonp is supported?